# Set the aliens straight by determining the missing figure in the progression

Tags: pattern, visual

> Aliens have come to Earth to see if there is intelligent life elsewhere in the galaxy (they weren't able to tell from our television broadcasts). Help them to come to the right conclusion by determining the missing figure.
>
> [image]

There is one "anomaly" in the progression, but this is not a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to use numpad notation; i.e. the top row is 789, middle row is 456, and bottom row is 123.

> One of the Xs 'bounces' up and down: 4 5 6 5 4 5 6 5...
>  One of them goes in a circle (but not in the corners): 8 6 2 4 8 6 2 4...
>  And one of them skips 3 every time, going counterclockwise: 7 6 1 8 3 4 9 2...

There are *many* other equivalent ways to write this, but in any case, the final answer is:

> the same as the first frame, since each cycle repeats every 8 frames (or a factor of 8).

Comment: I've got a different interpretation that has the same answer: one goes 45654565..., one goes 26842684..., and one goes 16729438... (in a star pattern).

Comment: @f'': Yeah, I mentioned there were more interpretations of it. I'll change it to that one, if you don't mind.

Comment: Yeah, it's interesting how so many different patterns can explain this. I had  rotators of 2,3 CW and a horizontal oscillator. One things for sure: the cycle of 8 frames.

Comment: @Marconius: Yeah, these things can be decomposed in a lot of different ways.